# Why do compilers only look backward for type and function declarations?

Tags: c++, c, parsing

This is purely to satisfy my own curiosity, but why are functions and types only resolved against those defined *earlier* in the code, rather than *anywhere* within the same scope?

Sometimes it shows up when functions need to call each other:

```
void foo(int depth) { bar(depth + 2); }
void bar(int depth) { if (depth > 0) foo(depth - 3); }
```

Where you either need to move bar to before foo, or declare bar beforehand:

```
void bar(int);
void foo(int depth) { bar(depth + 2); }
void bar(int depth) { if (depth > 0) foo(depth - 3); }
```

In more complex examples you may need to review the #include tree and #ifndef guards to figure out why your code does not recognize a function or type defined in some other file, and that's if you already know you're supposed to check for that.

---

And then of course there's this classic:

```
typedef struct {
    Node *next;
} Node;
```

Where you need to know that this is possible:

```
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

...but apparently many people don't so they just use 'void *' or 'struct Node' everywhere.

---

So, is there a reason why these compilers don't resolve forward too? I can understand the preprocessor only checking backward since things can be #undefined, but once a type or function is declared it's there for good and can't be overloaded by a later definition.

Is it for historical reasons, with the limited technology that was available when they were first developed? Or is there some logical ambiguity I'm missing?

Comment: I think it's more that it hasn't reached those functions yet, rather than it reading backwards.

Comment: There are a lot of C-isms here that would never appear in C++ code.

Comment: It's not the compiler, it's the way the language is defined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The language can be defined in terms of compiler effort.  Forcing definitions to precede their use reduces the number of passes required of the compiler.

Comment: ... and that's pretty much the answer, I think.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Plenty of language features/facts are constructed around feasibility, otherwise there wouldn't be much point in it. The removal of `export` is one sort of example.

Comment: @RobertHarvey simple answer: The C compilation model (TUs) sucks. Nowadays has no sense and only gives us problems (Headers recompiled many times per compilation increasing compiling times, templates only in headers, forward declarations of functions and types acrross TUs making your code a hole spaghetty, etc)

Comment: @Manu343726: So your proposal to fix the long compile times when a header changes is to.... increase the data processed during compilation by an order of magnitude?

Comment: FWIW, Objective-C methods don't have to be declared before they're used.

Comment: Also, class members can follow the inline function using them in C++.

Comment: Designing languages so a single-pass compiler could compile them was a strong goal back in the days when 64KB of memory cost a lot of money and reading the punch-card deck twice was unpractical.  It isn't actually true for C++, it allows defining inline functions that use member functions that are not declared yet.  A "1.5" pass compiler :)

Comment: They don't.  C and C++ are fairly strict in requiring everything to be defined before used, but Java, eg, allows a class to be defined after it's referenced, and other languages (though I can't name one) permit declarations to occur after references.  The original scheme of define-before-reference was mainly driven by single-pass compilers in limited-storage environments, and hence the motivation is no longer particularly compelling.

Comment: Ben Voigt's comment "@Manu343726: So your proposal to fix the long compile times when a header changes is to.... increase the data processed during compilation by an order of magnitude?" misleadingly conjures up a vision of tenfold increase of compile time if forward referencing was supported, silently ignoring that in in C++ class definition such forward referencing *is* supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is simply that "It would make it much harder to write a compiler if it didn't" - the language specification says that it has to be this way, but the reason for this wording in the language specification is that "it makes it easier to write a compiler that way". To some degree, it's probably also that in the old days, compilers would generate code "as they went along", and not read all the code in a translation unit (source file) first, then process it.

Bear in mind that C and C++ compilers are still being used on machines that don't have huge amounts of memory and very fast processors. So, if you try to compile LARGE amounts of code on a small capacity machine, then the "we don't want to read ALL of the source first, then prase it" approach makes more sense than on a 16GB, quad-core desktop machine. I expect you could load the entire source code for a fairly large project into memory all at once (for example, all of the files in LLVM + Clang is around 450MB, so could easily fit in memory on a modern desktop/laptop).

Edit: It should be noted that "interpreted languages", such as PHP, JavaScript and Basic, typically don't have this requirement, but other compiled languages typically do - for example Pascal has a special keyword `forward` to tell the compiler that this function exists, but I'm telling you what it contains later.

Both Pascal and C (and C++ because it's based on C in this aspect) allow for pointers to structures that aren't complete yet. Just this simple "you don't have all the information yet" means that the compiler has to build up the type information, and then "go back and fix it up" [obviously only as required]. But it allows us to do:

```
struct X
{
   struct X* next;
   ... 
};
```

or in C++:

```
struct X
{
   X* next; 
   ...
};
```

Edit2: This blog by Jan Hubicka, a GCC developer, explains some of the problems with "dealing with all the code at once". Of course, most of us aren't compiling Firefox and similar size projects, but large projects, when you have to deal with ALL of the code at once, do cause problems with "not enough memory available" even with modern machines if the developers don't "put the compiler on a diet from time to time".

http://hubicka.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-1-brief.html

Comment: You can refer to any class-member in an inline function definition of the class, always. At least since C++11, don't know about earlier.

Comment: Yes, pre-C++ 11 allows this too. Again, it means that the compiler has to pretty much read the entire class and then process it, as the compiler won't know what to do with the functions until it knows what the forward declarations are.

Comment: No forward declarations, that is reserved for things the programmer types. Just say, what members are outstanding.

Comment: If I remember correctly, PLL/1 didn't have this rule, so it isn't just because of the bad old days.

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, I mean that the compiler needs to read all the class, to find the content that was used but not yet defined. I don't mean that the programmer types forward declarations, but there are implicit "declarations" by using the members.

Comment: @EJP: I did not say ALL compiled languages from the past had this. I did say that compiled languages are more likely to have this, because an interpreted language probably needs all the code to fit in memory at once anyway... ;)

Comment: " and then "go back and fix it up" [obviously only as required].": I'm not a compiler expert but I'd think that a forward declaration (of a type, of a function) provides enough information for the compiler to emit the code right where the forward-declared entity is used. It doesn't have to re-visit, and may not be able to. The whole idea behind the "declare before use" is that it enables a one pass compilation. You can just _pipe_ the code through the compiler.

Comment: Yes, the compiler only reads the text once, but it needs to hold on to certain information (typically in some sort of list/vector/etc) and process again. An example of such a processing step can be found in my Pascal compiler project here: 
https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/parser.cpp#L408

The type declaration can be incomplete (it's a pointer to a type that hasn't been defined yet). When we get to the end of all the types defined, we go back and process again. It's not much, but it makes life harder.

Comment: @Deduplicator: it has always been so, that in a member function in a class definition one can refer to not-yet-declared members. it is *as if* those member function definitions were placed after the class definition. and for c++ it rather pulls the rug from under all of the speculations about why it isn't that way that it actually is...

Comment: @Deduplicator: just thought you might want to know, that's all. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that all necessary information of an entity being present when needed allows the compiler to translate a source file in a single pass. Cf. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/02/04/how-many-passes.aspx, for a comparison with C# (which doesn't require previous declarations; but then everything is in a class anyway).

C shares this feature with Pascal and a few other languages. Writing such a compiler is easier and, as others pointed out, tends to use less memory (but potentially increases compilation time, paradoxically, because the declarations in headers are being parsed/compiled over and over again for each translation unit).

Comment: The "hard" part of a compiler is actually in the later stages of the compile, which means that all the (required) code and data structures need to be there. Building these from source or intermediate form is a relatively small part of the compilation time (as long as files aren't on a server connected to your system with a piece of wet string, but that's an infrastructure problem, not a compiler problem - cache files locally, or some such, in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Because any kind of logical deduction requires some kind of "logical order of things".

You deliberately ignore the order of things, to express your point here. Ok, nice, but this is very ignorant.

In C and C++ you have an order that kind of tries to workaround some typical problems: declaration and definition. In C/C++ you can refer to things that are at least declared, even if they were not yet defined.

But, this separation or "declared" and "defined" is just a relaxation of logical order, which --- in the end --- is just a simplification of things.

Imagine a pure plain language sequence of expressions to describe your program (in contrast to any programming language, which tries to express the same, but even tries to "compile" in into some practical computer program): A is B, but B depends on C, but B is like C only if A is to B what D may be to A what C may be to A what D is to C.

WTF???

If you can deduce a real world solution to a dedicated real world problem in a kind that does not depend on any logical order, then you will know your answer, and you may become very rich, just by knowing it.